# Save Session Android

Tags: java, android, session, sharedpreferences

I want to do make my app save session to not login again when i kill the process : when i login in the Main.java he weel redirect me to Menu.java then after i kill the precess an runit again he should take me directly to Menu.java without login with saving the username

exactly like this tutu http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm

this is Main.java "Login Page"

```
public class Main extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText et,pass;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

public static final String data = "ett";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button18);

   exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(exit);

        }
    });

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", 
                    "Verification ...", true);
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();                          
                    }
                  }).start();               
        }
    });
}

void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.4/android/etc.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(data, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
            editor.putString("et", et.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this, Menu.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
            builder.setTitle("Erreur d'identification");
            builder.setMessage("Code ou mot de passe incorrecte")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });     

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });


}
```

}

Menu.java this wher should the app start after saving session

```
public class Menu extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menus);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button14 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button18);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Menu.this, emploi.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Menu.this, Maritimnews.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Menu.this, Resultats.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
        }
    });

    button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(Menu.this, Demande.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
        }
    });

    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(Menu.this, Apropos.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
        }
    });

    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(exit);

        }
    });


    }



}
```

i don't know where i put the sharedpreferces exactly to make it save the session 
the sharedpreferences there just for passing data between Main.java and Menu.java
i wan't to add another sheredPreferences to save session like facebook means when i login in Main.java ---redirecte--> Menu.java so if i close an run the app again he will start with Menu.java :) and Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you implement that way the user will login only once in your application and will be forever connected. the best is to do it this way:
first add a checkbox to login to let the user decide if he wants to save his login.
add sharepreferences if checked and delete sharepreferences if uncheck.
read sharedpreferences in the onresume() method of main activity and add some logic to intent directly to menu activity if preferences is not null

Comment: can you give an exemple ? beceause i'dont know where i put the code exactly

Comment: just add a checkbox to login xml and add logic to onclick event of login button. then add intent login to  @Override protected void onResume() {}

Answer (score 0):

I used mySharedPreferences that indicate to me if user already logged in, and I pass a int value from previous activity to know if the user just enter the app or not.

```
public class ConnectWithFaceBookActivity extends Activity{

    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    private SharedPreferences  mySharedPreferences;
    private String TAG = "ConnectWithFaceBookActivity";  
    private TextView lblEmail;
    private String accessToken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connect_with_facebook);

        mySharedPreferences =  this.getSharedPreferences( "facebook", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor= mySharedPreferences.edit();
        lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEmail);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int logout = i.getIntExtra("LOGOUT", 0);

        //checking if already sign in
        if(logout!=1 && mySharedPreferences.getString("email","")!="")//1 represent logout button preesed
        {
            String mString;
            mString= mySharedPreferences.getString("email","");
            lblEmail.setText(mString);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class); 
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();  
        }

        authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }); 

        // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends","email"));

        // session state call back event
        authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() 
        {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {

                Boolean open = session.isOpened();

                if (open) 
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                    accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
                    Request.newMeRequest (session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) 
                        {
                            if (user != null) 
                            { 
                                Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                                Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                                String str = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                                lblEmail.setText(str);

                                editor.putBoolean("isLogIn",true);
                                editor.putString("email",str);

                                //save the changes that you made
                                editor.commit();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class); 
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    editor.putBoolean("isLogIn",false);
                    editor.putString("email","");

                    //save the changes that you made
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void callFacebookLogout(Context context) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            if (!session.isClosed()) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                //clear your preferences if saved
            }
        } else {

            session = new Session(context);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);

            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                //clear your preferences if saved
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed your code to have a consistent 4 spaces/indent level (and cut down on blank lines to limit scrolling); but you really should also decide between putting opening `{`'s on the previous line or a new line.  On the previous line is the more common convention in Java; but either is acceptable as long as you're consistent.  Mixing the two looks ugly no matter what your preference is.